# char *p =NULL takes memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, heap-memory

My question is regarding the memory management of a 4GB addressable system
`char *p = NULL;`
Does it occupy any memory?
If so, where in the heap or stack and how much?
Also tell about `char **p=NULL;`

Comment: Where is your `p` declared? Locally in a function? Outside a function?

Comment: @AndreyT does it makes any difference? if so tell me for both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a typical 32 bit system, it takes 4 bytes.

Assuming your examples are a definition of a local variable in some function, those bytes are taken from the stack. Although:

- if the variable is not used elsewhere, the compiler may remove it altogether from the generated code;
- if the variable is used only locally and its address is not taken, it may be put into a register, so it doesn't occupy "regular" memory.

If, instead, it's a global variable (or, in general, a variable with *static storage duration*), on most systems there's a special region of memory (separated from the stack and the so-called heap) used for them. Often it's just a region of memory mapped directly from the executable image in copy-on-write mode. So here the 4 bytes are occupied both in this particular memory area, both in space inside the executable.

The same holds for `char **p`, which, in line of principle, has no reason for being bigger or different somehow from `char *`.

---

By the way, if `char * p` or `char ** p` were part of an aggregate data type (typically a `struct`), the space they take comes from wherever the `struct` is allocated - if the `struct` variable is a local variable, it comes from the stack, if it's allocated dynamically with `malloc` on the heap, if it's a global it comes from the special memory region for globals. Keep in mind that, talking about space taken by `struct`s, additional considerations about padding come into play.

---

Notice that all those are considerations valid for "typical" 32-bit systems; nothing stops some bizarre architecture from making `char **` different in size from `char *` (although I don't see any reason to do that). Still, you can perform a direct check by using the `sizeof` operator.

As far as the standard is concerned, I think that the only constraint imposed to pointer size is that any pointer to data can be converted to and from `void *` without loss of information (actually, the standard doesn't ever mention the stack or registers). Also, keep in mind that the compiler is allowed to do anything it wants as far as the "observable behavior" is coherent with what is requested from the standard, so there's no real guarantee on these implementation details mandated by the standard, although more details may be found in the documentation of the compiler you are using.

Comment: Otherwise - it will be located on stack. Same for `char ** p`;

Comment: What if it's a member on a dynamically allocated `struct`, is it on the stack then?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: it cannot be a member of a dynamically allocated `struct`, since it's not allowed to initialize them directly as OP did.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier No, it's whereever the struct is. But the syntax in OP's example isn't even valid for struct initalization, so that's kinda missing the question.

Comment: @MatteoItalia if afterwards it is allcoated memory with the help of malloc, then it occupies memory in heap?

Comment: @akash: the pointer itself doesn't change size, it's the data you allocated with `malloc` that takes space in the heap.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: My C is rusty so I didn't notice that, however I asked because it was a nuance that may have confused the asker (which following comments seem to have bear out). What lives where in what memory & how things are passed around is endlessly confusing to newbys, even in basic languages like c. Similar to the confusion that gives rise to the "Value types are always put on the stack" & "Objects are passed by reference" myths in the C# world. +1 BTW

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: you are right, and I should clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without context, both versions of your variable `p` will in general occupy memory for one `char*` and one `char**` respectively, and that's either automatic ("stack") or static ("global") storage. The size that's required is no larger than the size of a `void*` (typically one machine word).

The compiler is always allowed to behave "as if" this variable were stored in memory, but it may remove the variable entirely if it can substitute its value directly. In that sense there' s no absolute guarantee that your C construct will result in any particular concrete machine code.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is just a normal variable which can hold an adress. Wherever  a `char *` variable is created it will use memory, no matter what's the value of the variable. On 32-bit systems the typical size of a pointer is 32-bit and on 64-bit machines it's 64-bit. Like `int` or `long`.